What kind of genitive is involved in the sentence "A Mazda is a poor man's Ferrari'?
I'm not a linguist but am struggling to describe a similar locution in ancient Greek. It is not a simple genitive of possession since the poor man does not possess a Ferrari. It is not a genitive of quality (Smyth, Greek Grammar, 1390) since the Ferrari does not have the quality of being plebian. Is there a technical term for this kind of genitive?

"It is not a simple genitive of possession since the poor man does not possess a Ferrari." Why not? Language doesn't require a real world fact check before using idioms.

My father’s bike and my mother’s bike are both perfectly simple possessives – the fact that my father doesn’t own a bicycle, while my mother does, make no difference in that regard. If we needed real-world fact check confirmations to know whether a construction is a possessive or not, what would that make Schrödinger’s cat?

This is quite an interesting question. Whilst I'm not allowed to post it here, I would suggest you pose it to ChatGPT (4o), and then prompt it further. It seems able to answer this in a far more technical and deep sense, relating to ancient Greek sources too if asked. (Personally, I find the present discussions somewhat lacking in the technical depth and scholarly background that would be of interest here.)

@CobyViner - If you can correctly understand the response you get as being relevant and accurate, you presumably have the knowledge necessary to post your own answer here that meets your criteria.

@Obie2.0 While that's a nice thought and one I too had debated, unfortunately that's not so. After careful consideration, I regret that I cannot do so in any policy-compliant grammar. An unfortunate policy, to be sure.

Not that I personally think a long list of somewhat arbitrarily delineated and named uses of the Greek genitive with reference to ancient texts is necessarily a better answer to the question than pointing out that it is a metaphorical use of a genitive category that is more usually used concretely. What's the "grammatical rule" that lets someone say "my other car is a bicycle"? Does saying "This donkey is Yeshua's horse" require a different genitive than "This stallion is Yeshua's horse," or is it just a metaphorical extension of the latter? (Does some language separate these two genitives?)

@CobyViner - If there's some policy that writing a good answer to this question would necessarily violate (e.g. it would be opinion-based), then that is usually considered an issue with the question. If your concern is just that a language model could possibly come up with similar ideas to an answer that you might write, then the policies here do not actually prevent you from writing an answer.

@Obie2.0 Interesting points, and a great question. I regret I lack the expertise to provide any satisfactory reply, but I would refer you to this (I think quite excellent) work. The Greek forms are all well beyond me, so I can't actually even provide much of a summary. But interesting considerations and I hope a domain expert (ideally with substantial formal training in this specific area) might eventually provide a reply!

@Obie2.0 As it lacks specific relevance, all I will say in reply to your policy comment is that our interpretations differ somewhat. (Also, my own prior knowledge and expertise in this area is truly quite minimal.)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I am pretty sure grammars in the past combined syntax and semantics, but a modern perspective, as is found for example in the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language by Huddleston and Pullum, emphasizes the difference between syntactic forms and corresponding semantic structures. They are not in one-to-one correspondence; the same syntactic structure can be re-used for various semantic ones.
So instead of asking “what kind of genitive is this” in semantic terms, like, “what meaning is being implied here”, one could simply say, this is a genitive. Syntactically, it uses the features of the genitive transformation of a noun: man -> man’s.
Semantically, we can explore what it means perhaps by rephrasing it. For example, “A Mazda is like a Ferrari, except for poor people.” Or, “A Ferrari is to a normal/rich person as a Mazda is to a poor person.”
One thing to keep in mind is that “a poor man” here is not referring to a specific poor man in the class of poor men who actually exists in “the world”. Rather, it seems to be discussing the class of Mazdas, the class of Ferraris, and the class of poor men on a general level. One is making assertions about the abstract template of “Mazda”.
There is definitely more detail to go into, though.

Or: A Mazda is a Ferrari of a poor man.
